# Laravel 6 - Conditionally enable debug page on production mode

Tags: laravel

I used to run debug true in production when needed with Laravel 5 the following way:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'myipaddress' ? true : false),
```

However Laravel 6 doesn't let me use it, when I do artisan config:cache, artisan complains that:

> variable $_server['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not defined and exists.

Is there another way someone has found out to be working to do this with Laravel 6?

Comment: You can't cache dynamic configs.

Comment: Didn't have aproblem in the Laravel 5. But ok, any other suggestions how to achieve debug true in production only for certain user?

Comment: why you want to see if the ip is a specific ip? i'm asking to understand the context in order to se if there is a workaround... if i've undestand correctly, you want to see if the Ip of the request is the ip of your working station, in order to have debug to true if is you that are visiting the website

Comment: @berto99 I am enabling debug to specific IP. This is in production so I have to filter out who it is true for.

Comment: @EmJeiEn ok so what i've said is true... why not to use a middleware?

Comment: @berto99 I'm happy to but I do not know how to do it. I'm asking for help here how to do this :) If you do know how to achieve it I'd be delighted if you could answer with proper reply how to do it with Middleware :)?

Comment: to create a middleware just follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware and in the handle method you just need to change the config like this: `config(['app.debug' =>  $request->ip() == 'your ip']);`

Comment: @Berto99 any chance you could give a proper reply to question with info how to achieve that including all the steps needed? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cache dynamic configs. there is no request and no `$_server` when Laravel tries to cache your configs.

You must disable your debug on production (`APP_DEBUG = false`) and check the log for any errors.

But if you insist to enable app debug dynamically, you can use middleware:

1. Create a new middleware using Artisan command:

   ```
   php artisan make:middleware EnableDebug
   ```
2. This command will place a new `EnableDebug` class within your `app/Http/Middleware` directory. Modify it like this:

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Closure;

   class EnableDebug
   {
       /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           config(['app.debug' => $request->ip() === 'myipaddress']);

           return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```
3. List your middleware class at the end of the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

   ```
   protected $middleware = [
       //...
       \App\Http\Middleware\EnableDebug::class,
   ];
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those unfortunately lead to:    Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [request] does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I made a composer package that can turn on APP_DEBUG based on COOKIE and IP:
https://github.com/Benjaminhu/laravel-app-debug-dynamic

Usage (Dynamic enable APP_DEBUG via COOKIE & IP):

```bash
composer require benjaminhu/laravel-app-debug-dynamic
```

Setup `.env` (remember: in production mode alway set: APP_DEBUG=false!):

```
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_DEBUG_DYNAMIC_COOKIE_NAME=<CHOOSE COOKIE NAME>
APP_DEBUG_DYNAMIC_COOKIE_SECRET=<CHOOSE COOKIE SECRET>
```

If the data matches, the debug is activated dynamically!